# MSSQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 2005 New Query Template

Tags: sql-server-2005, templates, ssms

How do I change a default "New Query" template in SSMS 2005?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Posted this question as a reference, I did some googling, and found a [simple way](http://weblogs.asp.net/cabhilash/archive/2008/11/23/sql-server-management-studio-query-template.aspx) of doing it.

All you need to do is to edit SQLFile.sql located here: <%= your SQL install dir %>\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\SqlWorkbenchProjectItems\SQL\SQLFile.sql

Also, Ctrl+Alt+T will show you all the other templates in SSMS; and check out [Free SQL Server tools](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/11/20/Free-SQL-Server-tools-that-might-make-your-life-a.aspx) while you're at it.