# how do I do in SSMS to have a script loaded each time I press "New Query"?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014, ssms-2014

When I press New Query on SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), according to the following picture:

[image]

I would like the following script in a new tab.
would this be possible?

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO

-- SET XACT_ABORT ON will render the transaction uncommittable
-- when the constraint violation occurs.
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    ------------------------------------------------------




    ------------------------------------------------------
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- Test XACT_STATE for 0, 1, or -1.
    -- If 1, the transaction is committable.
    -- If -1, the transaction is uncommittable and should 
    --     be rolled back.
    -- XACT_STATE = 0 means there is no transaction and
    --     a commit or rollback operation would generate an error.

    -- Test whether the transaction is uncommittable.
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'The transaction is in an uncommittable state.' +
              ' Rolling back transaction.'
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END;

    -- Test whether the transaction is active and valid.
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'The transaction is committable.' + 
              ' Committing transaction.'
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;   
    END;
END CATCH;
GO
```

there is a very similar question on the link below, but it is not working for me. SSMS 2014.

[MSSQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 2005 New Query Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593047/mssql-server-management-studio-ssms-2005-new-query-template)

Comment: Are you sure the file got saved? It might be protected. It worked for me by modifying this file (for SSMS2014): C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\SqlWorkbenchProjectItems\Sql\SQLFile.sql

Comment: @PeterHenell spot on it worked!! the problem is that I was saving it at C:\Program Files and NOT at C:\Program Files (x86)

Comment: I will leave the question as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is ok to do in here, but I use code snippets for stuff like this. You could dl a free generator, such as https://snippetsgen.codeplex.com/
and save them under Code Snippets Manager (or Ctr + K , ctr + B). then accessing them is via shortcut too (for me, it's Ctr +K , Ctr + X). i throw a lot of frequently queried stuff here.

Answer (score 0):

For SSMS version 14, You can modify the template file at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\SqlWorkbenchProjectItems\Sql\SQLFile.sql